# Laravel CRON or Event process respond to api request via long poll - how to re-vitalise the session

Tags: php, laravel, redis

I have a `poll` route on an API on Laravel 5.7 server, where the api user can request any information since the last poll.

The easy part is to respond immediately to a valid request if there is new information `return $this->prepareResult($newData);`

If there is no new data I am storing a poll request in the database, and a cron utility can then check once a minute for all poll requests and respond to any polls where data has been updated.  Alternatively I can create an event listener for data updates and fire off a response to the poll when the data is updated.

I'm stuck with how to restore each session to match the device waiting for the update.  I can store or pass the session ID but how do I make sure the CRON task / event processor can respond to the correct IP address just as if it was to the original request.  Can php even do this?

I am trying to avoid websockets as will have lots of devices but with limited updates / interactions.

Comment: websockets in php block a process... but using node based solution doesn't have that limitation and socket.io could do what you want :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long poll is a valid technique. i think is a bad idea to run poll with session. since session are only for original user. you can run your long poll with php cli. you can check on your middleware to allow cli only for route poll. you can use [pthreads](https://github.com/krakjoe/pthreads)
to run your long poll use pthreads via cli. and now pthreads v3 is designed safely and sensibly anywhere but CLI. you can use your cron to trigger your thread every one hour. then in your controller you need to store a $time = time(); to mark your start time of execution. then create dowhile loop to loop your poll process. while condition can be ($time > time()+3600) or other condition. inside loop you need to check is poll exist? if true then run it. then on the bottom of line inside loop you need to sleep for some second, for example 2 second.

on your background.php(this file is execute by cron)

```
<?php
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

class Atomic extends Threaded {
    public function __construct($data = NULL) {
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    private $data;
    private $method;
    private $class;
    private $config;
}

class Task extends Thread {

    public function __construct(Atomic $atomic) {
        $this->atomic = $atomic;
    }

    public function run() {
        $this->atomic->synchronized(function($atomic) 
        {
            chdir($atomic->config['root']);

            $exec_statement = array(
                "php7.2.7",
                $atomic->config['index'],
                $atomic->class,
                $atomic->method
            );

            echo "Running Command".PHP_EOL. implode(" ", $exec_statement)." at: ".date("Y-m-d H:i:s").PHP_EOL;
            $data = shell_exec(implode(" ", $exec_statement));

            echo $data.PHP_EOL;

        }, $this->atomic);
    }

    private $atomic;
}

$config = array(
    "root" => "/var/www/api.example.com/api/v1.1",
    "index" => "index.php",
    "interval_execution_time" => 200
);

chdir($config['root']);

$threads = array();


$list_threads = array(
    array(
        "class" => "Background_workers",
        "method" => "send_email",
        "total_thread" => 2
    ),
    array(
        "class" => "Background_workers",
        "method" => "updating_data_user",
        "total_thread" => 2
    ),
    array(
        "class" => "Background_workers",
        "method" => "sending_fcm_broadcast",
        "total_thread" => 2
    )
);

for ($i=0; $i < count($list_threads); $i++) 
{
    $total_thread = $list_threads[$i]['total_thread'];

    for ($j=0; $j < $total_thread; $j++) 
    { 
        $atomic = new Atomic();
        $atomic->class = $list_threads[$i]['class'];
        $atomic->method = $list_threads[$i]['method'];
        $atomic->thread_number = $j;
        $atomic->config = $config;

        $threads[] = new Task($atomic);
    }
}

foreach ($threads as $thread) {
    $thread->start();
    usleep(200);
}

foreach ($threads as $thread)
    $thread->join();
?>
```

and this on your controller

```
<?php
    defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

    class Background_workers extends MX_Controller {

        public function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->database();
            $this->output->enable_profiler(FALSE);
            $this->configuration = $this->config->item("configuration_background_worker_module");
        }

        public function sending_fcm_broadcast() {
            $time_run = time();
            $time_stop = strtotime("+1 hour");

            do{
                $time_run = time();

                modules::run("Background_worker_module/sending_fcm_broadcast", $this->configuration["fcm_broadcast"]["limit"]);

                sleep(2);
            }
            while ($time_run < $time_stop);
        }
    }
```

this is a sample runing code from codeigniter controller.

Answer (score 3):

Clients poll for updates, APIs do not push updates.

REST API's are supposed to be stateless, so trying to have the backend keep track goes against REST.
To answer your question specifically, if you do not want to use websockets, the client app is going to have to continue to poll the endpoint till data is available.

Comment: Long poll is a valid technique, and for this specific use case would work well. The techniques I've seen in Laravel tend to keep the session open (`sleep`) and then respond at some future time which is a bit wasteful.

Answer (score 1):

`Long polling` requires holding the connection open. That can only happen through an infinite loop of `checking` to see if the data exists and then adding a `sleep`.

There is no need to revitalize the session as the response is fired only on a successful data hit.

Note that this method is very CPU and memory intensive as the connection and FPM worker will remain open until a successful data hit. Web sockets is a much better solution regardless of the number of devices and frequency of updates.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **notifications**. "browser notification" for web clients and FCM and APN notification for mobile clients.

Another option is using **SSE** (server sent events). It's a connection like socket but over http. Client sends a normal request, and server can just respond to client multiple times and any time if client is available (In the same request that has been sent).

Comment: Thanks - I believe SSE requires the session to be continued, which again ties up server resources. Will have a look at FCM and see if the Ionic App can use that (there are drivers for Laravel)